# How to decompile a  vm byte code into java

Tags: java, android, dex

Are there any tools for turning Android DEX those are VM bytecode files into corresponding Java sourcecode?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one of those decompilers here: http://www.java-decompiler.com/
Be warned though that unless you are decompiling code that has been compiled with the debug flags on, local variables will not have names.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/), then you can decompile it with whatever decompiler you want, such as [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).